# Set cursor anywhere in window in Vim

Tags: vim

How to setup Vim so you can f.e mouse click in the middle of new opened empty Vim window and place cursor exactly there ( f.e line 23 char 49), instead of line 1 char 1 because?

Is there better way than filling lines with spaces?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try `:set mouse=a virtualedit=all`. See [`:set mouse`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'mouse') and [`:set virtualedit`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'virtualedit')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cursor must be somewhere in a buffer and the screen lines that start with `~` are *not* part of the buffer so placing the cursor there is impossible, no matter how you set `:help 'mouse'` or `:help 'virtualedit'`.

You won't be able to achieve your goal without first populating the new buffer with empty lines.